# WebGL drawArrays generates white background

Tags: javascript, webgl

I have a simple WebGL application.
It has canvas and a pair of simple shaders:

```
<canvas id="render" width="320" height="240">
<div id="vertexShader" class="shader">  
    attribute vec4 position;
    void main()
    {
        gl_Position = position;
    }
</div>
<div id="fragmentShader" class="shader">
    precision mediump float;
    void main()
    {
        gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    }
</div>
```

The application code looks like this:

```
function getContext() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("render");
    return canvas.getContext("webgl");
}

function initContext(context) {
    context.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    context.clear(context.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
}

function getShader(shaderId, type, context) {
    var shaderSource = document.getElementById(shaderId).innerHTML;
    var shader = context.createShader(type);
    context.shaderSource(shader, shaderSource);
    context.compileShader(shader);
    if (!context.getShaderParameter(shader, context.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
      console.log(context.getShaderInfoLog(shader));
      return null;
    }
    return shader;
}

function initShaders(context) {
    var program = context.createProgram();
    context.attachShader(program, getShader("vertexShader", context.VERTEX_SHADER, context));
    context.attachShader(program, getShader("fragmentShader", context.FRAGMENT_SHADER, context));
    context.linkProgram(program);
    if (!context.getProgramParameter(program, context.LINK_STATUS)) {
      console.log("Could not initialise shaders");
    }
    return program;
}

function renderTile(context, program) {
    var tileBuffer = context.createBuffer();
    var tile = [
        1.0, 1.0, 0, 1.0,
        -1.0, 0, 0, 1.0,
        1.0, -1.0, 0, 1.0
    ];
    context.bindBuffer(context.ARRAY_BUFFER, tileBuffer);
    context.bufferData(context.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(tile), context.STATIC_DRAW);
    positionLocation = context.getAttribLocation(program, "position");
    context.enableVertexAttribArray(positionLocation);
    context.vertexAttribPointer(positionLocation, 4, context.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    context.drawArrays(context.TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
}

var context = getContext();
initContext(context);
var program = initShaders(context);
context.useProgram(program);
setTimeout(function() {
    renderTile(context, program);
}, 100);
```

It renders a simple triangle on a canvas.

The problem is that it sometimes renders a triangle on a white background although clear color is set to non-transparent black. (*in latest Google Chrome, Firefox is ok*)
While debugging I found that white background is rendered when `drawArrays` method is called.
But I can't understand why it is not black.

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JustMad/k8f7Q/2/) for your convenience.

Comment: I was really confused about this too. ztirom has the right answer, but to be more specific, this is apparently just a default behavior of WebGL canvases. I personally don't like this, and fortunately it can be disabled with a getContext setting: `canvas.getContext('webgl', { preserveDrawingBuffer: true })`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example you just have to clear your color buffer every "frame". Your background is black at first, then gets "overwritten" by your triangle (that vertices buffer), like you mentioned. 
You actually just do one clear in your init function at startup.

```
function initContext(context) {
    context.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    context.clear(context.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
}
```

Just add `context.clear(context.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);` to your update function, for example:

```
setInterval(function() {
    context.clear(context.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    renderTile(context, program);
}, 100);
```

See this updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k8f7Q/6/).

Comment: Thank you! But why it renders white background around triangle? I thought that only triangle borders and its inner space is redrawn after `drawArrays` is called...

Comment: @Just_Mad your canvas background is per default white, so in the first frame (on `initContext`) you set your canvas to black, then in your `Interval` you render a triangle and you change your frame. After that last change you don't set a new "background", so it gets white, because of your default setting in your CSS. Change that id in your CSS file to `background: black;` and your canvas will stay black. See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k8f7Q/7/). But this is only a quick and dirty solution.